# If two table have an identical column for handling relationship between them, is it better to separate the column to a different table?

Tags: sql, database, database-normalization

I am working in a database for a college application. There is a Routine table which holds all schedules for five days of a week(mon-fri) for all levels(classes).

Students in each level can also be divided into separate sections and their routine will differ based on their sections. So I thought of adding a "level", "section" column to the "Student" and "Routine" which shows in which section particular student is in and to which section a particular schedule belongs to respectively. With this I could match a particular students with only those routines of the section he/she belongs to.

But I think a better solution would be to create two new table called "Level" and "Section" which will hold the different level and sections in my college. With this the section table can reference level table to determine to which level this sections belongs to. The Student and Routine table will also hold a reference of to the section table so that I can easily match a student with correct routine. But the "Level" table is only going to have one column 'level' and "Section" table is also going to have only two columns 'section' and 'level'.

For this particular case which of the two approaches is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the second option but you do not need the table with only 'Levels'.

You should have Tables 'Classes' with Level and Section.
If a Level does not have a Section then this parameter can be NULL.
If you need to get a list of your Levels just do a DISTINCT query and you get the table with all the Levels, so there is no need for a second table.

This is what I would do.

Comment: I have used "level" column in multiple other tables. Since upto this point I hadn't thought about sections, this was ok. But now since I have different table for levels and sections it would be better to use "level" column as a foreign key in all those tables. But I cannot associate records for a those tables to a particular section only. For example. In "Unit" table, an unit is related to a level but not section. So I think creating separate table for "Level" and "section" is better. What do you think?